# How to specify in a file a list of files and folders to exclude with xcopy or robocopy

Tags: robocopy, xcopy

Windows 10
I want to run the xcopy or robocopy command in a .bat file.

I need to wildcard copy many files/folders, but exclude some files/folders.

I have tried xcopy with /exclude:filename, but I cannot find a definition online of how to specify the excludes in the exclusions file.  E.g., folder names with or without backslashes, one or both ends, etc.
I am trying it with about 30 items in the exclusions file.

What I have found online for robocopy just shows listing the files and folders to exclude on the command line.  Can I specify a file to list my exclusions in?  If so what is the syntax?
I need to list about 30 items in the exclusions file.

E.g., I want to copy “C:*.*”, but exclude some of the folders.

Thanks.

Comment: This can help use /XD to exclude directories. And use /XF to exclude file tyypw. https://superuser.com/questions/482112/using-robocopy-and-excluding-multiple-directories

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found what I consider 3 methods at that link.  I have not tried them yet, but they look very promising.